# Swiper thumbnail navigation do not work in build mode work in dev mode react next js application

Tags: next.js, navigation, thumbnails, swiper.js, init

in local mode swiper thumbnail navigation work but in build mode initial slide is not set active
and thumbnail navigation do not work but its work through arrow click .
in local its work through thumb nail and arrow both navigation
its React next js application
it work in yarn dev but when i make build it do not work

```
import 'swiper/css'; // also tried import "swiper/swiper.min.css";
export { Navigation, Thumbs, Pagination, Autoplay, Grid } from 'swiper';
export { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
export type { SwiperOptions } from 'swiper';


import {
  Navigation,
  Swiper,
  SwiperOptions,
  SwiperSlide,
  Thumbs,
} from '@/components/ui/carousel/Sliders'
import { productGalleryPlaceholder } from '@/public/assets/placeholders'
import { getDirection } from '@/utils/getDirection'
import cn from 'classnames'
import { Attachment } from 'lib/types/products'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { IoIosArrowBack, IoIosArrowForward } from 'react-icons/io'
import Scrollbar from '../Scrollbar'

interface Props {
  gallery: Attachment[]
  thumbnailClassName?: string
  galleryClassName?: string
}

// product gallery breakpoints
const galleryCarouselBreakpoints = {
  '0': {
    slidesPerView: 4,
  },
}

const swiperParams: SwiperOptions = {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 0,
}

const ThumbnailCarousel: React.FC<Props> = ({
  gallery,
  thumbnailClassName = 'xl:w-[480px] 2xl:w-[650px]',
  // galleryClassName = 'xl:w-28 2xl:w-[130px]',
  galleryClassName,
}) => {
  const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState<any>(null)
  const prevRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const nextRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const { locale } = useRouter()
  const dir = getDirection(locale)

  return (
    <div className="w-full xl:flex xl:flex-row-reverse">
      <div
        className={cn(
          'relative mb-2.5 w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md border border-border-base md:mb-3 xl:ltr:ml-5 xl:rtl:mr-5',
          thumbnailClassName
        )}
      >
        {!!thumbsSwiper ? (
          <Swiper
            id="productGallery"
            thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}
            modules={[Navigation, Thumbs]}
            navigation={{
              prevEl: prevRef.current!, // Assert non-null
              nextEl: nextRef.current!, // Assert non-null
            }}
            {...swiperParams}
          >
            {gallery?.map((item) => (
              <SwiperSlide
                key={`product-gallery-${item.id}`}
                className="flex items-center justify-center"
              >
                <Image
                  src={item?.original ?? productGalleryPlaceholder}
                  alt={`Product gallery ${item.id}`}
                  // width={650}
                  // height={590}
                  width={540}
                  height={440}
                  className="rounded-lg object-contain"
                />
              </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
          </Swiper>
        ) : (
          <Swiper
            id="productGallery"
            modules={[Navigation, Thumbs]}
            navigation={{
              prevEl: prevRef.current!, // Assert non-null
              nextEl: nextRef.current!, // Assert non-null
            }}
            {...swiperParams}
          >
            {gallery?.map((item) => (
              <SwiperSlide
                key={`product-gallery-${item.id}`}
                className="flex items-center justify-center"
              >
                <Image
                  src={item?.original ?? productGalleryPlaceholder}
                  alt={`Product gallery ${item.id}`}
                  width={540}
                  height={440}
                  className="rounded-lg object-contain"
                />
              </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
          </Swiper>
        )}
        <div className="absolute top-2/4 z-10 flex w-full items-center justify-between px-2.5">
          <div
            ref={prevRef}
            className="flex h-7 w-7 -translate-y-1/2 transform cursor-pointer items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-brand-light text-base shadow-navigation transition duration-300 hover:bg-brand hover:text-brand-light focus:outline-none md:h-8 md:w-8 lg:h-9 lg:w-9 lg:text-lg xl:h-10 xl:w-10 xl:text-xl"
          >
            {dir === 'rtl' ? <IoIosArrowForward /> : <IoIosArrowBack />}
          </div>
          <div
            ref={nextRef}
            className="flex h-7 w-7 -translate-y-1/2 transform cursor-pointer items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-brand-light text-base shadow-navigation transition duration-300 hover:bg-brand hover:text-brand-light focus:outline-none md:h-8 md:w-8 lg:h-9 lg:w-9 lg:text-lg xl:h-10 xl:w-10 xl:text-xl"
          >
            {dir === 'rtl' ? <IoIosArrowBack /> : <IoIosArrowForward />}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* End of product main slider */}

      <Scrollbar
        options={{
          overflow: { y: 'scroll' },
          scrollbars: {
            visibility: 'visible',
          },
        }}
      >
        <div className={`shrink-0 ${galleryClassName}`}>
          <Swiper
            id="productGalleryThumbs"
            modules={[Navigation, Thumbs]}
            onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
            spaceBetween={0}
            watchSlidesProgress
            freeMode
            observer
            observeParents
            breakpoints={galleryCarouselBreakpoints}
          >
            {gallery?.map((item) => (
              <SwiperSlide
                key={`product-thumb-gallery-${item.id}`}
                className="flex cursor-pointer items-center justify-center overflow-hidden rounded border border-border-base transition hover:opacity-75"
              >
                <Image
                  src={item?.thumbnail ?? productGalleryPlaceholder}
                  alt={`Product thumb gallery ${item.id}`}
                  // width={170}
                  // height={170}
                  width={70}
                  height={70}
                />
              </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
          </Swiper>
        </div>
      </Scrollbar>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ThumbnailCarousel
```

it should work in build mode as well as it working dev mode

Comment: Can any one please check this 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem also. What I did was:

1. Import the `FreeMode` module and add it to the `modules` parameter on the `Swiper` object for thumbnails, i.e.:

   ```
   import { Navigation, Thumbs, FreeMode } from "swiper/modules";

   <Swiper
     onSwiper={setActiveThumbnail}
     loop={true}
     spaceBetween={10}
     modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs]}
     slidesPerView={4}
     className="mt-[-20px]"
   >
   ```
2. On the main `Swiper` object, change your thumbs to
   `thumbs={{ swiper: activeThumbnail }}`, i.e.

   ```
   <Swiper
     loop={true}
     spaceBetween={10}
     modules={[Navigation, Thumbs]}
     thumbs={{ swiper: activeThumbnail }}
     grabCursor={true}
   >
   ```